# How would you solve $2xydx + (1+ x^2 )dy=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE problem : 
$$2xydx + (1+ x^2 )dy=0$$

First of all, I don't like this weird differential notation, but I assume I can just rewrite it as 
$$2xy + (1+ x^2 )\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

When I try to solve this, I get an integral with imaginary numbers, which I don't know how to tackle. 
$$\int\frac{2}{x+i}dx$$

I'm not sure if that's even necessary though, since it might be solvable in a more simple way.

**So how do we solve this ODE?**

Comment: Its already separable. Can't see it?

Comment: @Programmer2134: You have $$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{y}~dy =  \int \dfrac{-2 x}{x^2+1}~dx$$

Comment: Yes I know, but I don't know how to solve that integral. I tried to split the denominator into (x+i)(x-i).
But I now see that I should have just used the chain rule, since the numerator is the derivative of the denominator...

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Set $F(x,y)=(1+x^2)y$. Then 
$$
2xy\,dx+(1+x^2)\,dy=0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \frac{d}{dx}F\big(x,y(x)\big)=0.
$$
Thus
$$
y=\frac{c}{1+x^2},
$$
for some $c\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

From
$$2xy\text{d}x + (1+ x^2 )\text{d}y=0$$

we obtain

$$\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\text{d}x =-\frac1y\text{d}y$$

so that

$$\int \frac{2x}{1+x^2}\text{d}x =\int -\frac1y\text{d}y$$

which rewrites to (for $c\in\mathbb{R}$)

$$\log(1+x^2)=-\log(y)+c$$

Now we raise $e$ to both sides (for $C=e^c$, so $C>0$)

$$1+x^2=\frac1{y}\cdot C$$

and lastly, solve for $y$:

$$y=\frac C{1+x^2}$$

Comment: Just add constant $\ C\in{R}$

Answer (score 0):

> $$2xy + (1+ x^2 )\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

This is a separable differential equation, so that would be one approach.

Alternatively, note that with $f(x,y) = \left(1+x^2\right)y$ you can rewrite

> $$2xydx + (1+ x^2 )dy=0$$

using a total differential:
$$2xy \,\mbox{d}x + (1+ x^2 )\,\mbox{d}y=0 \iff \mbox{d}\, f(x,y) =0$$
And the solutions are then given by:
$$f(x,y) = c \to \left(1+x^2\right)y = c \iff y = \ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

Put $$z (x,y)=(1+x^2)y$$

we have

$$dz=2xydx+(1+x^2)dy $$
your equation is

$$dz=0$$
which gives
$$z=constante=C $$
or

$$y=\frac {C}{1+x^2} $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: To handle this problem while staying at the level of differentials, we may divide through by $y(1+x^2)$ to get $$0=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}dx + \frac{dy}{y}.$$

Both terms can then be understood as single-variable differentials i.e. $df(x)+dg(y)$. Both of these can be explicitly integrated, giving $f(x)+g(y)=$ const.

Comment: But this differential stuff is not actually well defined right? I'm taught to always think in terms of derivatives, and see the differentials only as an intuitive notation, so I'm always uneasy with differential notation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form. For introductory calculus, it isn't really defined, but it can be and is often used in differential geometry. It works.